# Custom .Primitive function in R

Tags: r

I known `*+* <- function(x,y){ x + y}` in R.

But if I want to write a function like `.print`.

And I can show `print(iris)` with using `iris.print`.

How do I custom my function in R?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use R's R3 classes.

A simple example. Assume we have a new data type --- a vector which we would like to print as a comma-separated string.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
# Assign a class attribute. The first element is the class of the object;
# the second element is the parent class
class(x) <- c("Foo", "numeric")
# Define the print method
print.Foo <- function(x) {
  cat(paste(x, collapse = ", "), "\n")
}
# The method is called just like this
print(x)
```